# Make Modal Div Scrollable & Not Page Background

Tags: html, css

Link:  http://wodgate.com/wp/

Instructions:  Click 'Rates' in the top navigation.

After clicking 'Rates' two divs appear:  A div for the main background and a div containing the content.  Right now when scrolling vertically, the entire `<body>` scrolls, but I need the `<body>` in a locked position and having only the top `<div>` scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes:

```
#modal-div {
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1002;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and when the modal shows give `body` this rule:

```
overflow: hidden;
```